# Algorithm to rotate a string?

Tags: algorithm

While I really just need a rotation algorithm, a string seems to be the easiest thing to do this with, although since this isn't for any specific language it really doesn't matter.How change

```
ab
c
```

to

```
b
ac
```

Comment: Well, that's not a right rotate... or a left rotate... I don't understand your sample at all.  In C++ we just write `std::rotate(first, mid, last)`

Comment: Could please give a precise definition of rotation? Moreover, I can see 2 strings in your example while the problem statement mentions only one.

Comment: How ever you do it you are going to have an algorithm that has linear complexity. For each char in the string there is operation. I suppose there might be scope for considering if you want to do an in place reversal or if you want to reverse the string into a new string. Either way the algorithm is sufficiently simple I wouldn't waste much thought on it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions. [I guess this can give you an idea](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-rotation/) (array rotation solution in C)

[image]

This one uses chars

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Left rotation of a string is to move some leading characters to its end, for example, if the input string is “abcdefg” and a number 2, two characters are rotated and the result
is “cdefgab”. */

void solution1(char *s, int n, int rotate) {
    char new_s[n * 2 + 1];
    strcpy(new_s, s);
    strcat(new_s, s);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) /* extract s from "abcdeabcde" */
       s[i] = new_s[i + rotate];
    printf("%s\n", s);
}
/* solution 2*/
void reverse(char *s, char *start, char *end) {
    char temp;
    while (start < end) {
        temp = *start;
        *start = *end;
        *end = temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }
}

void solution2(char *s, int length, int rotate) {
    char *first = s;
    char *first_end = s + rotate - 1;
    char *second = s + rotate;
    char *second_end = s + length - 1;
    if(s != NULL && length > 0 && rotate > 0 && rotate < length) {
    /* Reverse the n leading characters */
        reverse(s, first, first_end);
    /* Reverse other characters */
       reverse(s, second, second_end);
    /* Reverse the whole string */
       reverse(s, first, second_end);
    }
}

int main() {

    char s[8] = "abc";
    int n = (int) strlen(s);
    solution1(s, n, 2);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    solution2(s, n, 2);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs

```
sh-4.3#main 
cab
cab 
bca
```

It should be not so complex to modify it according the results you want to get.